# Getting problems implementing react-select package

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am working in a react app that is a form that contains a few dropdown components (from MS fabric).
I got a request asking for change some of these dropdown to combobox and the MS fabric combobox package doesn't work very well so I looked the internet and I found a package called React-select. 
I tested the package in a simple react app before implementing it in the real project and it worked very well. 
The problem is when I try to implement the same package in the real project. The problem is that as soon I implement the  component my app stop working. If I remove the line  the app works again.

The major difference between the test app and the real project is that in the project I am using Typescript. I have also other components in the project and just for testing I removed all of them but the problem remain.

No error messages in the developer console nor in the react app itself.

My implementation is like this:

Import the module: 
`import Select from "react-select";`

Inside componentDidUpdate:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: ISearchPersonFormProps): void {
        if (this.props != prevProps) {
            let civilServants = [] as any;

                        this.props.civilServants.forEach(civilServant => {
                civilServants.push({ label: civilServant.PKATBESKR, value: civilServant.Id })
            })
            
             this.setState(
                {
                     civilServants: civilServants
                });

        }
```

In my ISearchPersonFormProps I have this interface:

`civilServants: ICivilServant[];`

And in the render method i use the  like this: 
`<Select options={this.state.civilServants} />`

The civilServants state is of type IDropdownOptions[].

I tested the state of civilServants just before the Select-line and it contains all the information that I want to use in the Select component.

When I remove this Select-line the app works again otherwise nothing shows on the screen and no error message shows in the dev console.

Some info of my app: 
React version: 16.11.10
Typescript version: 3.7.2
React-select version: 3.0.8
@types/react-select version: 3.0.8

Any comment will be helpful,
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
this is the code for the component:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  TextField,
  Dropdown,
  IDropdownOption,
  Checkbox,
  PrimaryButton,
  Stack,
  Label
} from "office-ui-fabric-react";
import { ISearchPersonFormProps } from "./ISearchPersonFormProps";
import { ISearchPersonFormState } from "./ISearchPersonFormState";
import Select from "react-select";

export class SearchPersonForm extends React.Component<
  ISearchPersonFormProps,
  ISearchPersonFormState
> {
  constructor(props: ISearchPersonFormProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      civilServants: [],
      selectedOption: null
    };

    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: ISearchPersonFormProps): void {
    if (this.props != prevProps) {
      let civilServants: any[] = [];

      this.props.civilServants.forEach(civilServant => {
        civilServants.push({
          value: civilServant.Id,
          label: civilServant.PKATBESKR
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        civilServants: civilServants
      });
    }
  }

  private _handleChange = (selectedOption: any) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedOption
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.selectedOption)
    );
  };

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISearchPersonFormProps> {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    console.log(this.state.civilServants);

    return (
      <div className="search-form">
        <Stack horizontalAlign="start" tokens={{ childrenGap: 20 }}>
          <Stack horizontal tokens={{ childrenGap: 25 }}>
            <Select
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this._handleChange}
              options={this.state.civilServants}
            />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code for the porp interface:

```js
import { ICivilServant } from "./ICivilServant";

export interface ISearchPersonFormProps {
  civilServants: ICivilServant[];
}
```

This is the code for the state interface:

```js
export interface ISearchPersonFormState {
  selectedOption: any;
  civilServants: any;
}
```

The ICivilServant is the interface that is used when the data is fetched from the DB.

The console log in the component shows that the data from the DB is correctly fetched.
But as I said before, as soon I add the Select component the app stop working without any error message.

**UPDATE 2:** Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "rk-proper",
  "description": "Displays forms and listings (mostly) for everything regarding the solution.",
  "configurationType": "Web Part",
  "cewpHtmlContent": "<div id=\"proper-webpart-container\">​</div>",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"webpack --config webpack.dev.js --watch\" \"gulp serve\"",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.release.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "configure-sp": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ../StartDevelopment.ps1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-table": "^6.8.5",
    "@types/react-tabs": "^2.3.1",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.9.10",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/sharepoint": "^2016.1.6",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-serve": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.54.0",
    "react-table": "^6.10.3",
    "react-tabs": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of Select component use? Are you adding value and onChange handler as props?

Comment: Hi, no I am not using value or onChange. As I understand the only mandatory property is options. I will use onChange later when the component itself start to work. Here is a example how to use the component: https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-react-select/

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your component where you use react-select and declare it? This snippet is not enough to see where the problem is. Have you tried adding the component with empty options object ?

Comment: I will post the code soon, I need to take hand of an issue in another project first. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with the code for the component and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvcvv?module=/example.js). Instead of `value` prop they are using `defaultValue`. Take a look of the [documentation](https://react-select.com/home) and try to change it in your code to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tested again the component but this time I used just the only extrictly necesary packages and components in order to run the app and is working. So it seems to be a package in the package json that collide with react-select. I updated the post again and I added the complete package.json to see if there is something there that doesn't work with react-select.

Comment: Well I found the problem. Every time when it adds a new package I need to rebuild the entire application since the bundled code get uploaded to a SP site. It is not enough with installing the package but it needs reconfigure also.